# DIV Horizontal Scroll Bar to be the main horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css, html

I have a layout with a container and then within that container is another div for the content. I have it set so that if a table is bigger than the container, there will be a scrollbar.

However, many of the tables are long, so in order to get to that horizontal scrollbar, you have to scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page scroll to the right then scroll back up to the top of the page to see the information.

Is there a way to make it so the div's horizontal scroll bar is in the default/main horizontal scrollbar position?

```
body    {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #e8d7b5;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
    _text-align: center;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#bg {
    z-index: -999;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

div {
    border:none;
}
a   {
    color:#000000;
}
a:hover {
    color: #B89626;
}
li  {
    list-style-image: url(Bullet.gif);
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 97%;
    min-height: 700px;
    overflow: auto;
    *height: 700px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    _text-align: left;
    padding: 0px 7px 7px 7px;
    background: #ffffff;
    }

#content {
    width: 99%;
    overflow-x: auto;

}
.navigation {
    background: #003b5b;
    border:3px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0px;
    border-color: #011d2d;
    width:100%;
    height: 30px;
    }
.standardtab {
    background: #011D2D;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    height: 25px;
}
.nonstandardtab {
    background: #0D4664;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

There is my css. I have a container then a div for my content, which has the horizontal scrolling. I need the scrollbar of content to be the main scroll bar.

Comment: May be you can fix the height of table ?

Comment: I'm working with an oracle database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to have a floating horizontal scrollbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552684/possible-to-have-a-floating-horizontal-scrollbar)

Answer (score 0):

Set a height on the container and overflow:hidden; on the body to remove the default body scrollbars.

Comment: The you'll need to post your code or an example on a site like jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you fix the height of table to height of page/container and include vertical scrollbar. So you can see the horizontal scrollbar on the screen, instead of scrolling till bottom of table and then reaching the h-scrollbar.

Not exactly solution to your problem but may be an alternative.