# Primefaces datatable horizontal scrollbar floating

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsf, primefaces

In primefaces datatable, is that possible to make the scrollbar floating and always can be seen in the bottom ? For example in a datatable there is 100 table row,the horizontal scroll bar is actually hidden below. Users have to scroll to the very bottom in order to do the horizontal scrolling which is not quite user friendly.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle so we can see what you're working with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552684/possible-to-have-a-floating-horizontal-scrollbar

Comment: Why not just make the datatable have a scrollheight?