# HTML/CSS add a horizontal scrollbar at bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a web page with large table full screen. Number of rows are fixed at 20. And it should be scroll-able horizontally. Currently I use overflow feature to get the horizontal scroll bar.

```
 overflow: 'hidden', overflowX: 'scroll',
```

But then I need to scroll down to see the horizontal scroll bar. I want scroll bar fixed at the bottom of the page. So it is always visible and user can easily navigate the table. Please see below image for example. How can I add such scroll bar?

[image]

PS: I am using react-semantic-ui

Comment: I need to show the scroll bar at bottom of the page all the time. Right now I have to scroll down the page to end of the table to see the horizontal scroll bar. In Ubuntu also.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552684/possible-to-have-a-floating-horizontal-scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

Just place a div inside your div. As long as the child div has its width set it will overflow and the scroll bar will appear I think this is what you want. If you need to set the height of the outer one then use the height:100vh so set the outer div to be the height of the viewport.

Hope that helps.

```html
<div style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll; height: 150px; ">
  <div style="width: 800px; background-color: blue;">

    <br/>Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test 
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test 
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
    <br/>Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: `100vh` will not be reduced by the horizontal scrollbar. Also OP didn't want a vertical scrollbar in the div.

Comment: You lose the fixed header if you put everything in a div