# Floating Horizontal Scrollbar in Angular 2+

Tags: css, angular, scrollbar

In Angular 6 I have a wide and long table. The issue is to scroll horizontally the user needs to go to the bottom of the table in order to access the scrolls.

I would like to implement a floating horizontal scrollbar, which floats the horizontal scroll bars when the table is in view. I came across these solutions using Jquery but am struggling to implement this in Angular 6 (or 5,4,3 etc). Does anyone have solution for this or can help me out on how to implement in Angular? Thanks so much in advance.

[Demo](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Floating-Scrollbar-Plugin-jQuery-Floating-Scroll/)

[JQUERY Plugin](https://github.com/Amphiluke/floating-scroll#initialisation)

[Jquery Solution - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552684/possible-to-have-a-floating-horizontal-scrollbar)

Comment: You could use [`ngx-scrollbar`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-scrollbar)

Answer (score 0):

**solution 1:** if you looking for how to use *jQuery* with *Angular* you can achieve by first add *jQuery* and *`floatingScroll plugin`* to `angular.json` file in `"scripts": [...]`

to use *jQuery*

*TS*

```
....
declare let $: any;    // you can use "jQuery" keyword instead of "$"

@component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: ['...'],
  styleUrls: ['...']
})
export class JqueryExampleComponent implements onInit {

  constructor(private eleRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    $(this.eleRef.nativeElement).find('yourTableSelector').floatingScroll();
  }
}
```

when you use `$(this.eleRef.nativeElement)` that gonna get the *tree root* of the `component` dom then `.find('yourTableSelector')` to get the `element` you want.

**solution 2:** there's alternative library to achieve floating scrollbar or custom scrollbar in general one of this is [ngx-perfect-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-perfect-scrollbar) i use it and it gives you good features to handle your scroll and track his behavior take a look on it ... you can choose to allow *vertical* or *horizontal* scrollbar with some `css` like `position: fixed` and `javascript` functionality to *show* or *hide* the scrollbar if table in view or not you can achieve what you want.

Comment: i had the same problem, i used nx-perfect-scrollbar, but i dnt know how to make it sticky/keep-floating, can you help please

Answer (score 0):

For floating scrollbar without the need of other JS libraries you can use `handy-scroll` - https://www.npmjs.org/handy-scroll

Usage is following:

```
npm install handy-scroll
```

and then use it in your Angular files:

component.ts

```
import handyScroll from 'handy-scroll';

export abstract class Component implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

    @ViewChild('floatingScrollbar')
    private _floatingScrollbar: ElementRef;

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (!!this._floatingScrollbar && handyScroll.mounted(this._floatingScrollbar.nativeElement)) {
            handyScroll.destroy(this._floatingScrollbar.nativeElement);
        }
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        if (!!this._floatingScrollbar) {
            handyScroll.mount(this._floatingScrollbar.nativeElement);
        }
    }

}
```

component.html

```
<div #floatingScrollbar>
    content with scrollbar
</div>
```